# Procuring a Limited Term Driving License in Utah, USA and its validity?

Tags: usa, student-visa, driving-license, indian-citizens, driving

Moving to Utah for work.
Visa Status: F-1 Student. 
Driver License: Indian (in English).

- Would I need to give a test (written/road) to get the Limited-Term Driving License (LTDL)?
- What would be the validity of the LTDL in my case?
- Can I drive anywhere in the USA with the LTDL?
- Can the LTDL be used as a REAL ID, to board domestic flights?
- Is a LTDL renewable?

I have all the documents listed here:
https://dld.utah.gov/wp-content/uploads/sites/17/2015/01/DLD-335-Brochure-Rev-2016-05.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There's some more info [here](https://dld.utah.gov/licensingid-cards/limited-term-driver-licenseid-card/).

It doesn't answer all your questions.

- You will have to take written and road tests.
- "The expiration date of your license would be the date of your legal presence document or five years, whichever is sooner; or one year from the date of issuance if there is no expiration date"
- Yes, you can drive anywhere in the USA with the card
- This is unclear. Regular driver's licenses from Utah do meet REAL ID requirements. I suspect a Limited term DL would be compliant too.
- It does not say. The Asylee/Refugee section says that it can be renewed if the holder can now pass an English language written test when the first license expires after 4 years.

Comment: As I understand it, the limited term is required for Real ID compliance.  I believe that some states even give licenses that have a limited term for Real ID but a longer term for driving privilege.  It would be very surprising indeed if the license were not acceptable for Real ID.

Comment: I agree with @phoog. Real ID requires that DL/ID cards expire when legal presence does, so it seems like the purpose of a DL that is issued with that constraint would be Real ID compliance. California Real ID DLs issued to non-immigrants don't have a special name but do have their expiry set to the end of legal presence.